# iMac won't boot. No keyboard recognition

Tags: keyboard, macos, hardware, startup

I know that there are a lot of people that ask for help when their iMacs won't boot, but in all sites they tell you to use keyboard commands to reset NVRAM or something like that.

This case is **different, after an installing an update for El Capitan and restarting, my iMAC wont boot at all. Only the background led screen comes up. None of the keyboard commands work. It seems that it doesnt recognize the keyboard.**

Is there anything to do? Or should I take it directly to apple center?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please clarify?  What's the "background led"?  When you say none of the keyboard commands work, which ones did you try?  Did you hold down `Option` to select a new boot disk?

Comment: Background led is the backlight of the screen turning on. The screen shows nothing but you can see that the screen is backligthed. 
I followed everything in here: https://www.jorgedelacruz.es/2015/05/27/apple-resolviendo-pantalla-negra-al-encender/

Comment: Do you get any beeps or chimes?

Comment: None. The only thing that we were able to do is to speed up the fan at top speed by pressing twice or 3 times the power button. But there is no sound.

Comment: It's time to take it into Apple.  You have a hardware failure.

Comment: We are looking for the invoice. Here in Nicaragua you cannot make use of waranty without the invoice :'( Thank you